# Firebase user is null after page refresh

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I first log in and use my web application, I'm able to retrieve the authenticated user and access that user's info from the database. However, as soon as I refresh the page, I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null".

I was able to debug this a bit and see that when I originally log in, the ComponentDidMount() of my authentication component (which is a higher-order components that wraps my App component), which checks for an authenticated user by calling onAuthStateChanged, gets called before the ComponentDidMount() of the component which fetches data. However, when I refresh, the order of the calls is switched, and my authentication component gets called after. My end goal is to be able to get the uid of the logged in user in order to fetch their data from the database.

Below is my withAuthentication component:

```
import React from 'react';

import AuthUserContext from './context';
import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase';

const withAuthentication = Component => {
  class WithAuthentication extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        authUser: null,
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.listener = this.props.firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(
        authUser => {
          authUser
            ? this.setState({ authUser })
            : this.setState({ authUser: null });
        },
      );
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      this.listener();
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <AuthUserContext.Provider value={this.state.authUser}>
          <Component {...this.props} />
        </AuthUserContext.Provider>
      );
    }
   }

      return withFirebase(WithAuthentication);
    };

export default withAuthentication;
```

I then use this higher-order component to wrap my root App component, like so:

```
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      {indexRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
        return <Route exact path={prop.path} component={prop.component} key= 
   {key} />;
          })}
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );



export default withAuthentication(App);
```

This root app component is then rendered in my root index.js file

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <FirebaseContext.Provider value={new Firebase()}>
      <App />
    </FirebaseContext.Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Comment: Please share code in codesandbox

Comment: I think the normal sequence is that children's ComponentDidMounts run earlier than their parent's one (which is logical, as you cannot say that a component is mounted until all of its children has been mounted). I am not sure how is it work with HOC, but can be the same. I suggest to pass some `isAuthed` boolean down to wrapped component, and implement a getDerivedStateFromProps in there. When this auth prop swithes to true, trigger the data fetch.

Comment: @UmairFarooq Just added in my code

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you log in, at first `authUser` is null then you login and `authUser` is assigned user object and in some other component `authUser.uid` is used and it works well.

For the next time when you reload page, login page is not opened as you are already logged in so it renders other component where `authUser.uid` is used. As by default `authUser` is null as default state is `null` and `onAuthStateChanged` is async which means it doesn't executes immediately, so the other component where `authUser.uid` is used gives error. In the component you `uid` is used, you can do following e.g.:

```
authUser ? authUser.uid : ''
```

Comment: Assuming that I do this in my component where I use the uid, how can I fetch the data once the authed user gets fetched? As of now, if I use your approach, the authUser will get set to ' ' and doesn't get reupdated.

Comment: You can use `firebase.auth().currentUser;`. Also in componentDidMount please check value of `authUser` by consoling. If value is ok, then in `AuthUserContext.Consumer` user value should be available